# Grade Setup Wizard through API call

Tags: desire2learn

I'm pretty new to API and our implementation of Brightspace is in it's infancy.  I'm wondering, can we configure the settings under the grade setup wizard through an API call? When I reference the API list, non of them seem to fully reference what that setup wizard task does, which is why I'm asking for clarification.  Our goal is to setup/copy a course and have the setting from the setup wizard be apart of that automated course copy through the API call.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Brightspace application APIs let you [create and manage](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade) grade objects, categories, and values, as entities. They also let you manage some of the same general gradebook setup or configuration that the grades setup wizard lets you specify (the grading system at play, how to treat null grade values, and the ID of the default grade scheme).

However, there are some settings exposed in the setup wizard that aren't directly accessible via the API (for example, some of the options for managing the view that students and gradebook managers have over the gradebook).